# How to format complex number output with negative or zero values

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Please I need to write a program that takes two complex numbers from the user and output their difference. Complex numbers are those numbers in the form of a+bi, where a and b are real numbers known as the real and imaginary parts respectively. Thus, the difference between two complex numbers a1+b1i and a2+b2i is (a1-a2)+(b1-b2)i. I wrote the codes as

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class cmp {
    private:
        double re, im;
    public:
        cmp(double a, double b) {re=a; im=b;}
        friend cmp operator+(cmp&, cmp&);
        void show() {cout<<re<<" + "<<im<<"i"<<endl;}
};

cmp operator+(cmp& p, cmp& q) {return cmp (p.re-q.re, p.im-q.im);}

main() {
    double m1, n1, m2, n2;
    cout<<"Give two complex numbers: "; cin>>m1>>n1; cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Give another two complex numbers: "; cin>>m2>>n2; cout<<endl;
    cmp c1(m1,n1);
    cmp c2(m2,n2);
    cmp c3=c1+c2;
    c3.show();

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

However, when you look at the difference (a1-a2)+(b1-b2)i, if

1. b2>b1, then the imaginary part in the difference will be negative. For example (10.5+2i)-(5+4i)=5.5-2i. But, the program can't display that and display 5+-2i instead. How can my program be in usual maths format?
2. a1=a2 and/or b1=b2, 0 is/are displayed in the program unlike the usual format in maths. For example, mathematically, (4+7i)-(4+5i)=(4-4)+(7-5)i=2i. But this program will display 0+2i instead. How can I solve this problem too?

Please I need a clue on how to overcome these. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Your question is not clear, as your title mentions "overloading", while your body text asks a different or much more vague question.  Be more specific - how does your question relate to operator overloading?  What is the actual question you are trying to resolve?

Comment: I think you can see how I overload '+' operator in the program and my questions are stated at the end of each of those two list I mentioned.

Comment: Indeed, there is code depicting an overloaded operator.  However, the questions are worded in a way that is not clear and is difficult to understand what you are trying to accomplish.  Please consider revising in a way that clarifies or simplifies the problem at hand.

Comment: Okay Doc Brown, thanks.

Comment: @SouthpawHare: I think the question is clear - only the title did not match the question. I have corrected that.

Comment: @DocBrown I think the title change helped substantially, good job.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to make your `show()` method test for these special cases and handle them explicitly.

- If one of the components is zero, only display the other one (and don't display `+`).
- If both are zero, display zero.
- Don't display `+` if the imaginary portion is negative.
- *As Jan Hudec mentions*, if something is close enough to zero that it will print as zero, you probably want to make sure you treat it as zero, also.

There is no shortcut to this; just put some `if` statements in there.

(I assume you are doing this for educational purposes, but if not, you should be aware that [complex numbers are part of the C++ standard library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/complex/).)

Comment: I know. I just want to make use of operator overloading in this problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @YYG: why do you insist on "operator overloading" - your question is about how to implement the "show" member function, this has **nothing** to do with overloading. How the "+" operator works is completely independent from that. Of course, you could also overload the "<<" operator for your class (and call the "show" method from there), but that would be worth a new question (or just a google search, I am sure you will find plenty of examples).

Comment: The `+` can be shortcut, because standard library can be made to print positive numbers including `+` using `showpos`. But if you want to skip printing zeroes too, that can't be. Also don't forget about the case when both are 0 and don't forget about values that are not zero, but print as zero due to rounding.

Comment: I'd say the part in parenthesis should be put first.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can rewrite the show function like this

```
void show() {cout<<"("<<re<<") + ("<<im<<"i"<<")"<<endl;}
```

(so that the parentheses are shown to make the result clear)

Or you can make it this way,

```
    void show()
    {
        if (re==0 && im>0)
            cout<<re<<" + "<<im<<"i"<<endl;
        else if (re==0 && im<0)
            cout<<re<<" "<<im<<"i"<<endl;
        else if(im==0 && re>0)
            cout<<re<<" + "<<im<<"i"<<endl;
        else if(im==0 && re<0)
            cout<<re<<" + "<<im<<"i"<<endl;
        else
            cout<<re<<" + "<<im<<"i"<<endl;
    }
```

This way, all the positive values will be shown with the leading '+' sign and the negative will be anyway shown with the '-' sign. Good Luck! :)

Comment: Rage it works but creates another problem as well. When you run the program and input (10, 2) and (5, 2) for example, '+' sign appears in the first part as +5-2i. Also, the '0' that always appear when the real and/or imaginary parts are equal, remains as well, example inputting (4, 1) and (4, 9) gives +0-8i. Please run it and see what I mean. Thanks.

Comment: @YYG Yes, you are right! I didn't think about the 0 case. That's a very good point you raised. +1 to your question :). Well, I have edited my answer and its correct now.

Comment: Rage, please run it again with those examples I gave before and see. Still it isn't working, may be is not possible with operator overloading, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

In C, you could use `+` flag to force + or - sign on number. For streams you need to handle the situation yourself. Nothing is easier to make simple function:

Here is templated version to work for anything that implements < operator and << operator:

```
template <typename T>
std::string forceSign(T number){
 std::string ret;
 std::stringstream helper;
 ret=(number<0)?'-':((0<number)?'+':'\0');
 helper<<number;
 helper>>ret;
 return ret
}
```

you can then use:

```
void show() {cout<<re<<" "<<forceSign(im)<<"i"<<endl;}
```